# Como mudar a cor de fundo de uma imagem?

Tags: jquery, css, imagem

Preciso mudar a cor branca de fundo de imagens usando programação.
Alguém sabe como proceder?

Comment: É possível que o camarada que negativou a pergunta explique por qual razão fez isso?
A pergunta está mal formulada, está postada no lugar errado ou é só porque não sabe responder?

Comment: Olá @Vitor André, (já me livrando não fui eu que votei negativo kkk), mas sua pergunta está com muita informação desnecessária, tente editar sua pergunta e mostrar objetivamente o seu problema, sem essa parte de algo que você fez no passado mas não lembra(se você não lembra imagina a gente? rsrsrs). Por exemplo se seu objetivo é mudar o background de uma imagem(suponho que seja a tag <img>) use a propriedade background-color do css.

Comment: Valeu Bruno. Vou editar.
A intenção foi só dar uma descontraída, mas ok, tem razão.
De qualquer forma, minha ideia é alterar a cor branca de fundo de uma série de imagens que serão adicionadas em um slide.
O usuário não vai editar suas imagens para ter a cor de fundo do carrossel e também não quer usar branco de fundo no carrossel. Então estou tentando achar uma solução pra ele.
Achei uma solução usando Javascript no Stackoverflow em inglês, mas só funciona em html5 e queria um pouco mais versátil, pois como disse já usei uma solução similar no passado.

Comment: Sua pergunta ficou muito mais objetiva agora, concordo plenamente com as palavras do Bruno. Estava com muitas informações desnecessárias e acabava tirando o foco do real problema. Desculpe ter votado contra, o fato de você ter voltado e se preocupado em editar lhe mostra comprometimento. Vou retirar o voto contra.

Comment: Obrigado Simão. E só questionei o voto negativo porque não houve feedback. Mas sim, acho importante colaborar com a comunidade e seguir as diretrizes. Obrigado novamente.

Comment: Tem alguma pagina de teste para ver se o background que aparece é realmente da foto? Pois pode ser outro elemento que esteja causando isso.

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso

```
<img class="suaclasse" src...>
```

css

```
img.suaclasse {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); // ou uma cor que você preferir.
}
```

Comment: Bruno, bacana essa solução. Tinha me esquecido disso.
Mas eu queria mudar uma imagem jpg mesmo. Ou um png sem transparência.

Comment: O que acontece é que o cliente vai cadastrar imagens para um slide (carrossel). Ele não vai editar cada imagem que pegar e remover  fundo ou procurar apenas imagens com fundo transparente - seria bom se fizesse, mas preciso contar que não vai. Então eu queria uma forma de trocar o fundo branco pela cor do fundo do slide, sacou?
Pois daí eu coloco como uma exigência que as imagens tenham fundo branco ali, o que não exige conhecimento do cliente e nem lhe toma tempo.

Comment: Trocar a imagem em si, não tem como(a não ser que alguem apareça com uma técina inovadora aí kkkk), você pode definir uma cor fixa de fundo no slide e pedir para que as fotos tenham a mesma cor.

Comment: Aqui tem uma solução, mas funciona com canvas (html5) e queria ver se achava uma solução cross browser.
http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/479112-resolvidomudar-cor-da-imagem/

Comment: Nessa eu não vou saber te responder pois nunca fiz isso(e muito menos sei usar canvas ;p).

Comment: Beleza. Obrigado Bruno.
Essa dúvida não é muito trivial mesmo...
Valeu pela atenção.

Comment: Precisar de algo mais estamos aí.